# The HTTP status code "0" is not valid in laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

Sorry If my post is not clear, this is my first time.
Here is the error that show when i use this function  *[Http status code 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMTOA.png)*
This is the code that I try to use for my shopping cart increase item and decrease item. I use in laravel 5.5
I try to put the code here but somehow it didn't work so i upload image
[Click here to see my code function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIws1.png)

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <section id="cart_items">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="breadcrumbs">
                <ol class="breadcrumb">
                    <li class="active">My Shopping Cart</li>
                </ol>
            </div>
            <div class="table-responsive cart_info">
                @if(Cart::count())
                    <table class="table table-condensed">
                        <thead>
                        <tr class="cart_menu">
                            <td class="image">Item</td>
                            <td class="description">Product Name</td>
                            <td class="price">Price</td>
                            <td class="quantity">Quantity</td>
                            <td class="total">Total</td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        @foreach(Cart::content() as $item)
                            <tr>
                                <td class="cart_product">
                                   {{ $loop->index+1 }}
                                </td>
                                <td class="cart_description">
                                    {{$item->name}}
                                    {{--<p><img src="{{asset('images/'.$product->photo->file)}}"> </p>--}}
                                </td>
                                <td class="cart_price">
                                    <p>${{$item->price}}</p>
                                </td>
                                <td class="cart_quantity">
                                    <div class="cart_quantity_button">
                                        <a class="cart_quantity_down" href='{{url("cartEdit?product_id=$item->id&decrease=1")}}'> - </a>
                                        <input class="cart_quantity_input" type="text" name="quantity" value="{{$item->qty}}" autocomplete="off" size="2" readonly>
                                        <a class="cart_quantity_up" href='{{url("cartEdit?product_id=$item->id&increment=1")}}'> + </a>
                                        &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='{{url("cartEdit?product_id=$item->id&remove_item=1")}}'><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a>
                                    </div>

                                </td>
                                <td class="cart_total">
                                    <p class="cart_total_price">${{$item->subtotal}}</p>
                                </td>
                                <td class="cart_delete">
                                    <a class="cart_quantity_delete" href=""><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                        @endforeach
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2"></td>
                            <td>Cart Total</td>
                            <td colspan="2">${{Cart::subtotal()}}</td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3"></td>

                            <td colspan="2" ><div align="center"><a class="btn btn-danger update" href="{{url('clearCart')}}">Clear Cart</a>
                                <a class="btn btn-danger check_out" href="{{url('checkout')}}">Check Out</a></div></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        @else
                            <p>You have no items in the shopping cart</p>
                        @endif
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section> <!--/#cart_items-->

@endsection
```

When i run the code and click '+', '-' buttons,it show me The HTTP status code "0" is not valid. I don't know why it show like it.
  [This is how my cart look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92EvB.png)
Here is my controller for cart

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Order;
use App\Product;

use Cart;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;
use function Sodium\compare;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

class CartController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function add(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
    {
        /*update/ add new item to cart*/
            $input = $request->all();

            if($file = $request->file('photo_id')) {
                $name = time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();
                $file->move('image', $name);
                $photo = Photo::create(['file'=>$name]);
                $input['photo_id'] = $photo->id;
            }

            if (Request::isMethod('post')) {

                $product_id = Request::get('id');
                $product = Product::find($product_id);
                Cart::add(
                    [
                        'id' => $product_id,
                        'name' => $product->name,
                        'image' => $product->photo_id,
                        'qty' => 1,
                        'price' => $product->price
                    ]
                );
            }
//            dd(Cart::content());
             return redirect('/products');
        }
    public function cart() {


        //increment the quantity
        if (Request::get('product_id') && (Request::get('increment')) == 1) {
            $rowId = Cart::search(function ($cartItem, $rowId) {
                return $cartItem->id === Request::get('product_id');
            });
            $item = Cart::get($rowId->keys()->first());
            Cart::update($rowId->keys()->first(), $item->qty + 1);
        }

        //decrease the quantity
        if (Request::get('product_id') && (Request::get('decrease')) == 1) {
            $rowId = Cart::search(function ($cartItem, $rowId) {
                return $cartItem->id === Request::get('product_id');
            });
            $item = Cart::get($rowId->keys()->first());
            Cart::update($rowId->keys()->first(), $item->qty - 1);
        }
        //remove the item
        if(Request::get('product_id')&&(Request::get('remove_item')==1)){
            $rowId = Cart::search(function ($cartItem, $rowId) {
                return $cartItem->id === Request::get('product_id');
            });

            Cart::remove($rowId->keys()->first());
        }
        return redirect('/cartView',compact('user','orders'));
    }
    public function checkout(){
        $id = Auth::id();
        $items=Cart::content();
        $total=0;$orderID=0;
        //return Order::all();
        if(count(Order::all())) {
            $orderID = Order::orderBy('orderID', 'desc')->first()->orderID +1;
        }else{
            $orderID = 1;
        }
        //return $orderID;
        foreach ($items as $item){
            //return $item->rowId;
            $total += $item->subtotal;
            Order::create([
                'orderID'=>$orderID,
                'userID' => $id,
                'image' => $item->image,
                'cartRowID' => $item->rowId,
                'itemID' => $item->id,
                'itemName' => $item->name,
                'qty' => $item->qty,
                'price' => $item->price,
                'subtotal' => $item->subtotal,
                'returnOrder'=>0,
            ]);


        }
        Cart::destroy();

        return view('order')->with('items',$items)->with('total',$total);

    }
}
```

Comment: there is no 0 http status code

Comment: @AnarBayramov I have updated my post, now you can see the error as pic in Http status code is 0. Thanks for reply

Comment: I think the problem is here `return redirect('/cartView',compact('user','orders'));` since you have no `$user` and `$orders` variables

Comment: Thanks @Alexey you solve my problem. Thanks a lot, you save a lot of my time, I remove compact('user','orders') and it work well. I compact those variable without using is. Thank for your reply. You make my day